# Drupal 7 Views hover

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have created a views that showing various nodes in a ul list .. and for each node shows some field, such as a picture and the title of the node.

Now with a mouseover event I want to show other field of the same nodes in a small pop-up .. what is the best way to do this?
Is there something that the views module provides for doing so? 
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a specfic module for your use case
but there are 3 ways you can do this

- Create a PHP field in your view and code it in any way you want.  For this you must enable a module called Views PHP.
- Write a jQuery file (for OnHover functionality) and add it to your view using drupal_add_js()
  in the header section (you can add a header to the view) of the view.
- Write your own theme file.  The theming info is provided in views->advanced->others->theme

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Popup Views integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup_views_integration). See the [Demo](http://ajax-form-entity.emerya.com/views-popup-integration) in action.

> It provides a Views global field that can reuse the other Views
>   fields. It will be output a link that will trigger a popup.